# UITapGesture Error, Recognizes Tap In Wrong View

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

Heres The Problem: I want to test the TapGestureRecognizer with an NSLog but the TapGestureRecognizer functions anywhere except in the UIWebView and I have no idea why...

Heres My Code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(bookmarker:)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
[tapGesture release];
   }
```

Heres The IBAction:

```
-(IBAction)bookmarker:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)trecognizer{
NSLog(@"TAPPED");
}
```

This is the view I want it to function in:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UPor.png

And this is the view it functions in:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGmwq.png

(Sorry with less than 10 rep points I can't post pics )

Comment: `self.view` probably doesn't point to the correct view

Comment: any ideas on how to point it in the right direction? @elcanibal

Comment: Is the TapGestureRecognizer functioning in both two views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out webviews don't accept TapGestureRecognizer because it has its own set of gestures so to implement it:

in Header make UIGestureRecognizer delegate

(in viewDidLoad)

```
tapGesture.delegate = self;
```

Then implement:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer

{
 return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding your recognizer to your top view, any subview of that view will also trigger the gesture recognizer's action.

Per doc.

> Attaching a gesture recognizer to a view defines the scope of the represented gesture, causing it to receive touches hit-tested to that view and all of its subviews. The view retains the gesture recognizer.

You could do a check of your recognizer's touch location and see if it is somewhere inside your subview.

```
- (CGPoint)locationInView:(UIView *)view
```

Then do the check.

```
bool CGRectContainsPoint (
   CGRect rect,
   CGPoint point
);
```

Writing from memory, hope it works:

```
CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
CGRect rect = subView.frame;
bool inside = CGRectContainsPoint(rect, point);

if (!inside) {
    //do your code
}
```

Comment: Im still a noob so how exactly would i specify the check for the tap gesture recognizer?

Comment: Actually I just found out that the webview is stopping the tap from working, it works anywhere else but it won't work in the webview...any ideas?